# JPA @ElementCollection on HashMap with generics returns duplicates

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, generics, hashmap

This one is giving me fits.

**Problem Statement:**

When fetching a `Marklar` from the database, it is returned with duplicated `Foo`s. Specifically, there are as many `Foo`s as there are elements in the `bars` HashMap. For example, if I am saving a `Marklar` with **one** `Foo` in its `FooCollection`, and if `bars` is:

```
{0, "data1", 1, "data2", 2, "data3"}
```

I will get **three** `Foo`s in the `FooCollection` when I read it back. What is going on?

**Definitions:**

I have the following class structure:

```
   Foo<T>
     ^
     |
     | 1:M
FooContainer
     ^
     |
     | 1:1
<<Marklar>>
```

A `Marklar` has a `FooCollection`, which has several `Foo`s. A `Foo` is a generic class defined as:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
public class Foo<T> {

  @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private final Map<Integer, String> bars = new HashMap<>();

  @Type(type = "java.lang.Class")
  private final Class<T> clazz;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
  @Convert(converter = PatternConverter.class)
  private Pattern pattern;

  public void addBar(Integer key, String bar) {
    bars.put(key, bar);
  }

  public Foo(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  public Foo() {
    this.clazz = null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Foo)) return false;
    Foo<?> foo = (Foo<?>) o;
    return Objects.equals(getId(), foo.getId())
        && Objects.equals(getBars(), foo.getBars())
        && Objects.equals(getClazz(), foo.getClazz())
        && Objects.equals(getPattern(), foo.getPattern());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getId(), getBars(), getClazz(), getPattern());
  }
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

When fetching a `Marklar` from the database, it is returned with duplicated `Foo`s. Specifically, there are as many `Foo`s as there are elements in the `bars` HashMap. For example, if I am saving a `Marklar` with **one** `Foo` in its `FooCollection`, and if `bars` is:

```
{0, "data1", 1, "data2", 2, "data3"}
```

I will get **three** `Foo`s in the `FooContainer` when I read it back. What is going on?

**Definitions:**

I have the following class structure:

```
   Foo<T>
     ^
     |
     | 1:M
FooCollection
     ^
     |
     | 1:1
<<Marklar>>
```

A `Marklar` has a `FooContainer`, which has several `Foo`s. A `Foo` is a generic class defined as:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
public class Foo<T> {

  @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private final Map<Integer, String> bars = new HashMap<>();

  @Type(type = "java.lang.Class")
  private final Class<T> clazz;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
  @Convert(converter = PatternConverter.class)
  private Pattern pattern;

  public void addBar(Integer key, String bar) {
    bars.put(key, bar);
  }

  public Foo(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  public Foo() {
    this.clazz = null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Foo)) return false;
    Foo<?> foo = (Foo<?>) o;
    return Objects.equals(getId(), foo.getId())
        && Objects.equals(getBars(), foo.getBars())
        && Objects.equals(getClazz(), foo.getClazz())
        && Objects.equals(getPattern(), foo.getPattern());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getId(), getBars(), getClazz(), getPattern());
  }
}
```

`FooContainer`:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
public class FooContainer {

  @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

  @OneToMany(targetEntity = Foo.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private final List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addFoo(Foo foo) {
    foos.add(foo);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof FooContainer)) return false;
    FooContainer that = (FooContainer) o;
    return Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId()) && Objects.equals(getFoos(), that.getFoos());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getId(), getFoos());
  }
}
```

`Marklars` are fetched from the `MarklarRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface MarklarRepository extends JpaRepository<Marklar<?>, UUID> {}
```

A `Marklar` is an abstract class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Marklar<T> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    @Convert(converter = UriConverter.class)
    private final URI baseUri;

    @Type(type = "java.lang.Class")
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    private boolean enabled = true;

    public Marklar() {
        this.baseUri = null;
        this.clazz = null;
    }

    public Marklar(@NotNull URI baseUri, @NotNull Class<T> clazz) {
        this.baseUri = baseUri;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }    
}
```

Implemented as a `DefaultMarklar`:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public final class DefaultMarklar<T> extends Marklar<T> {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private final FooContainer fooContainer;

    public DefaultMarklar() {
        super();
        this.fooContainer = null;
    }

    public DefaultMarklar(
            @NotNull URI baseUri, @NotNull Class<T> clazz, @NotNull FooContainer fooContainer) {
        super(baseUri, clazz);
        this.fooContainer = fooContainer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `bars` is considered a separate bag by Hibernate, and eager fetching of multiple bags simultaneously can result in cardinality problems such as this.

I removed `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` from the `Bars` map, and added the
`@Transactional` annotation to the calling method, and all is well. Also, I replaced any direct references to lazily loaded fields (such as in `toString()` methods) with calls to their respective getters.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Fetching type from Lazy to Easy as @Tomas recommended solves the duplication, however it also impact the results.

If you want to keep the EagerType to EAGER, just specify the FechMode to Select:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)    
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
```